# Changing the order of integration using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

Write down the integral

$$\int_0^1 \int_x^ {\sqrt 3x} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dydx$$

as an integral/integrals in polar coordinates in two ways:

$(i)$ integration with respect to $r$ first and $\theta$ second

$(ii)$ integration with respect to $\theta$ first and $r$ second. [Hint: reduce the problem to an integral involving r only]

Part (i) is straightforward like the question that is linked to this question however how would I make $\theta$ a function of r?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is closely related to [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584145/is-int-02-int-x-sqrt-3x-f-sqrtx2y2dydx-int-pi-4-pi-3).

Comment: That's really helpful for part (i) but what about for part (ii)?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers. Please, [edit] the post accordingly.

Comment: Sorry! I'll edit it as soon as I get a chance, any chance you could help with part (ii) please?

Comment: There you go,  I have edited it! Any chance of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can cut the region into 2 pieces, a circular sector bounded by $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{3}x$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$ and the part of the triangular region with vertices $(0,0), (1,1), (1,\sqrt{3})$ which is outside this sector.

This gives $\displaystyle \int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} f(r) \;rd\theta dr\;+\;\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2\int_{\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{r}} ^{\frac{\pi}{3}} f(r)\; rd\theta dr$

$\;\;$(since $x=1\implies r\cos\theta=1\implies\cos\theta=\frac{1}{r}$)